# Estimate of peoples sharing the same first name, last name and date of birth over a population

Tags: statistics, birthday

I am aware of the birthday paradox (more than 50% likeliness of two people sharing the same day of birth). My question is somehow related to this, but with more variables (and unknowns).

Given a total population of lets say 50 million people, I am interested in people who share the same first and last name as well as the same date of birth. I presume that the likeliness of such a combination to exist in reality is close to 100% given the large population.

However, what I would like to estimate (no precision required here), is how many of those cases exist.

I guess it strongly depends on the distribution of names and date of birth. So lets assume that the most frequent first name has a 1.5% occurence and possibly can be best described using an inverse sigmoid function (not sure about the exact distribution). Roughly the same distribution applies to the last name.

How could I possibly calculate such an estimate and what else would I need to know?

Comment: This is very vague.  You'd need to model dependence...in large families, many people might share names. Celebrity can cause an increase in the usage of certain names. I'd think that would depend on a lot of complex factors (some cultures object to assigning names with living relatives, others embrace that).  If you have a set of assumptions you want to make, you need to make those explicit.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is vague. I am rather interested in a general approach and would completely leave out cultural factors. I guess what I am looking for is not a concrete answer, but to understand what I would need to get into the right direction and hopefully come up with a very simplified formular.

Comment: If you leave out cultural factors, I don't think the calculations will have much relation to reality.  If, say, you just declare that you have a number of independent  (discrete) random variables attached to each person you can certainly ask for the probability that two people match in all dimensions.  Given the number of cases here, you'll want to simulate that, but there should be no difficulty with that.

Comment: Ohh, simulating this is a great idea. I actually do have enough real data available to push this back into a domain that I feel comfortable with (programming). I guess I was too focussed on finding the answer with a formular. Thanks @lulu

Comment: Simulation is definitely the way to go.  Write the code flexibly, so that you can play with various assumptions.  Even if you ignore most cultural aspects you'll still need to keep some basic factors.  Gender, of course (as first names are deeply linked to that), and some basic correlations (some first name/last name combinations are much more or less likely than others).

Comment: First name and last name (assuming a culture were these make sense and nobody goes by a name like Ƭ̵̬̊) are certainly not independent variables - or else Sheldon Cooper's idea that "Mohammed Lee" is the most common name combo would be right